# automate a dump of information_schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm looking for a way to backup all the database on MySQL.  I've written a batch file which runs mysqldump and it's working fine.  Unfortunately I'm using MySQL 5.0 and can't upgrade to the newer version which includes the information_schema in the mysqldump.

Can anyone let me know of how I'm supposed to dump this database?  I've been trying for the last 8 hours and just can't get it work!

Hope someone can help.

Cheers

Alex

Comment: Why do you want to backup the information_schema database? MySQL will automatically populate that once you start re-importing dumps.

Comment: It will all be automatically repopulated?  I didn't know that!  That's fine then, if it will be repopulated when I import the backups back in then it's all good.

Comment: I'll post it again as an answer so when people land on this question they'll automatically see the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to back up the MySQL's `information_schema` database. MySQL operates and maintains this database itself and it will automatically repopulate it when a dump is being imported.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would! Tapping head to tell it to remember.